# Change dateformat mailchimp archive folder

Tags: javascript, mailchimp

I have on a website of mine a archive of e-mails created by Mailchimp. This is simply done with the archive code. However, all things on the website (including emails) is written in dutch but the dateformat on the website is in English.

I was wondering if I could change that in Mailchimp itself (would be great) but I wasn't able to find this. I was also thinking about writing a simple javascript which changes this format. However, looking a the HTML-output of the archive code made me realise this is not going to be easy. I have pasted the current HTML-output below. And below that the HTML-output I actually want.

```
<div class="campaign">08/30/2013 - <a target="_blank" title="Opent nieuw tabblad" href="http://us6.campaign-archive2.com/?u=3e4e337060c7c9e901a57d3c8&amp;id=5f541494e5" class="external">Activiteitenkalender Volkstuinen Waregem September 2013</a></div>

<div class="campaign">30/08/2013 - <a target="_blank" title="Opent nieuw tabblad" href="http://us6.campaign-archive2.com/?u=3e4e337060c7c9e901a57d3c8&amp;id=5f541494e5" class="external">Activiteitenkalender Volkstuinen Waregem September 2013</a></div>
```

To be honest the only thing I actually really need is how to get the 08/30/2013 as a single variable. When that is done I'm fine and I can go on.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just a pity no one answered my question. So, I tried on my own. Here is the code I used.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( ".display_archive" ).children().each(function() {

    var tekst = $(this).html();
    var datum = tekst.substr(0,10);
    var splitted = datum.split("/");
    var newhtml= tekst.replace(datum, splitted[1]+"/"+splitted[0]+"/"+splitted[2]);
    $(this).html(newhtml);



});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Providing you only want to switch between European (dd/mm/yyyy) and American (mm/dd/yyyy) format, you can do this directly in the Mailchimp account settings - no need for code. See "Date Format" in http://kb.mailchimp.com/accounts/account-setup/how-can-i-set-my-account-defaults

By the way, the date format you were seeing isn't "English" - in the UK we use the same format as you, it's the Americans who are different.